# How to operate file with dots in its name by Windows cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wildcard

For example

```
E:\2012.12.25  NO.23  Peter\Dailylog.txt
E:\2012.12.27  NO.12  John\log.txt
E:\2012.12.29  NO.25  Amy\log.txt
E:\2012.1.1  NO.23  Peter\bug .txt
E:\2013.1.2  NO.12  John\recoder.xml
E:\2012.1.3  NO.12  John\log.txt
```

Then, I want to put all  John's folders into a folder;
like this

```
E:\John\2012.12.27  NO.12  John\log.txt
E:\John\2013.1.2  NO.12  John\recoder.xml
E:\John\2012.1.3  NO.12  John\log.txt
```

I have tried

```
move "E:\*John" E:\John
```

but failed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command **MOVE** used with directory names does not move the directory, but renames the directory.

The batch code below produces for the input example the output:

```
E:\Amy\2012.12.29  NO.25  Amy\log.txt
E:\John\2012.12.27  NO.12  John\log.txt
E:\John\2013.1.2  NO.12  John\recoder.xml
E:\John\2012.1.3  NO.12  John\log.txt
E:\Peter\2012.12.25  NO.23  Peter\Dailylog.txt
E:\Peter\2012.1.1  NO.23  Peter\bug .txt
```

Here is the batch code with comment lines between main code at top and the subroutine at bottom doing the folder movements.

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /AD /B E:\*.*.*NO.* 2^>nul') do call :CheckFolder "E:\%%I"
goto :EOF

rem The subroutine CheckFolder first splits up each folder name passed
rem to the subroutine into strings using dot and space as delimiters.

rem Of interest is just the sixth string which is assigned to loop
rem variable B which can contain itself dots and spaces. The first
rem 5 strings (year, month, day, NO and number) are not of interest
rem for determining the target folder name for the current folder.

rem A folder which can't be split up into at least 6 strings is ignored
rem for further processing as this is most likely one of the target folders.

rem The target folder is next created if not already existing. If creation
rem of target folder fails, the current folder with files to move is ignored.

rem Next all files in current folder are moved to the target folder and
rem the current folder is removed which is only successful if the current
rem folder contains now no files or subfolders.

:CheckFolder
set "FolderName="
for /F "tokens=5* delims=. " %%A in ("%~nx1") do set "FolderName=%%B"
if "%FolderName%" == "" goto :EOF
if exist "%~dp1%FolderName%\%~nx1" goto MoveFolder
md "%~dp1%FolderName%\%~nx1"
if errorlevel 1 goto :EOF

:MoveFolder
move /Y "%~1\*" "%~dp1%FolderName%\%~nx1\" >nul
rd "%~1"
goto :EOF
```

**Edit** according to comment regarding `E:\2012.12.29 NO.25 Amy(later)\log.txt`.

On processing a folder name like `2012.12.29 NO.25 Amy(later)` the command line

```
for /F "tokens=5* delims=. " %%A in ("%~nx1") do set "FolderName=%%B"
```

assigns to ignored loop variable `A` the string `25` and to loop variable `B` the string `Amy(later)` which is assigned next to environment variable `FolderName`.

To get just `Amy` from this folder name it would be necessary to change this code line to

```
for /F tokens^=6^ delims^=^(.^  %%A in ("%~nx1") do set "FolderName=%%A"
```

Now an opening parenthesis is also interpreted as string delimiter like a dot and a space and just string 6 which is `Amy` is assigned to loop variable `A` which is assigned next to environment variable `FolderName`.

The strange looking syntax for the options is needed here as `(` has a special meaning for Windows command interpreter and therefore can't be easily specified as string delimiter as literal character.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `move /?`
- `rd /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`

See also the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `>nul` (suppress standard output) and `2>nul` (suppress error output) whereby the redirection operator `>` is escaped on `2>nul` with caret character `^` to be interpreted as redirection operator on execution of command **DIR** and not already on parsing the **FOR** command line.

Comment: Thank you first. I shall learn these commands later.By the way,why doesn't Microsoft design this wild cards more powerful?Is this design a logical consideration?

Comment: I have changed the root  directory   on "E:\*.*.*NO.*" to correspond my situation.                                                                                                          Then  I got such folder named like "%~dp1%FolderName%",is there any place I need change?

Comment: Please ask Microsoft why wildcards in paths are not possible. You have to change just __twice__ ``E:\`` in second batch file line on changing parent folder path to something different. Everything else is written to work independent on parent folder which is the reason for using `%~dp1` (drive and path of parent folder) in subroutine instead of ``E:\``.

Comment: Hello,thank you.I got a headache now,I may deal it tomorrow.Best wishes.

Comment: Well,I got it.Thank you.I should save it to a bat file and run it.And if there is something after the name  as a remark in the folder's  name,like, E:\2012.12.29  NO.25  Amy(later)\log.txt，where can I put the last ‘*’？